# Removing Chrome

Tags: apt, google-chrome

I am having trouble getting Google Chrome off my system. I installed from Google's website (probably a bad idea) and it appeared to work, but I was never able to launch the program. Any time I do any apt-get operations, I get the following at the end:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up google-chrome-stable (46.0.2490.71-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I had resorted to manually deleting files (again, bad idea I am aware), and it looks to me like the lack of an icon that I deleted is causing problems. I have tried everything to delete, reinstall and delete, purge etc. but I simply can't fix this error.

Comment: Try reinstall: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable` then update your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, then purge Chrome: `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: @RaelGugelminCunha After the first command I get the "Errors were encountered while processing..." message. After the second it says "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable:i386 : Depends: libappindicator1:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f." I get that message again after doing the third command.

Comment: Is your system 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @Pilot6 64-bit. Ok, I reinstalled and then purged both versions of Google-chrome-stable, and was going to comment that it's working but I lost Internet. When I did sudo apt-get autoremove it looks like it removed my network-manager, would that be the problem? I'm not sure what to do now, I'm typing this from my phone

Comment: You trying to install a wrong version of Chrome. You are installing a 32-bit version.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm aware of that. But somehow I have them both installed. I am trying to remove them, not install them.

Comment: I believe this problem has been solved. Thanks to @RaelGugelminCunha for the suggestions (if you make that into an answer I'll accept it). I now have a new problem, but I will use a separate question for that.

Comment: @NotNotLogical I've put as an answer. Hope you get your system working again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reinstall, using the `.deb` with `sudo dpkg -i <debfile>` or using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable`.

Then update your system with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Then purge Chrome: `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`.

Comment: Note for users with exact problem given in post: I had to do this for both google-chrome-stable AND google-chrome-stable:i386.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. After installing `google-chrome-beta`, somehow apt refuses to list `google-chrome-stable` as an installed package.